# Best way to use second computer as desktop mirror

Tags: kubuntu, display, screencast

I'm looking for a good way to cast my Ubuntu desktop screen to another Windows computer on the same local network.

I've tried setting up a RTMP server, and streaming using OBS. I've also tried using [this method](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-studio-send-an-udp-stream-to-a-second-pc-using-obs.455/) of directly streaming through UDP. However, both of these methods have about 2 seconds of lag.

Are there any faster ways of streaming my desktop?

Answer (score 0):

VNC would be a really good option for you. Here is a link to an [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04) that walks you through setup and configuration. I have used VNC in the past with great success.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is VNC able to share the current desktop session? Never used VNC before but I know that some other RDP servers create a new desktop session for every connection

Comment: If I remember correctly I believe it will create a new desktop session. It's intended for remote desktop access and control. Are you trying to live stream your desktop to windows while you are using the Ubuntu macine? If so, I would probably look into a video capture card for your Windows machine. That would be the best way to remove the lag your experiencing over the network.